# How does "Music I Like" work?

Tags: icloud, music, homepod

It used to be that I could tell my HomePod to play "Music I like" and it would play a few hours, I would tap it to stop, and the next day I could tap it again and it would continue with the song that I had interrupted.  And I could do this for weeks.

But the last month or so, I start it, and it doesn't last the evening before it stops playing.

One day I decided to run it from my Mac, telling my Music app (via Siri) to play music I like.  I turned on my Home app on my phone.   I could see the songs played both places.  Later on, when the music had stopped, I saw my Mac's app stuck at the beginning of a song, and my phone's app was stuck at the end of a different song.  Pressing the "=" button didn't do anything.  I quit and restarted my music app to unstick it.

How do I get it working the way it used to work?

Should it keep playing "Music I like" forever, or is there a limit?